# C++ Parsing with Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, parsing

What level of C++ parsing can be done with Eclipse for plugin development? I'm interested in knowing if there is a way that I can access C++ class types, method signatures, etc and create another class using the information that I gather from the original class parsed/read/analyzed.

I've looked at many C++ front end tools such as EDG, ROSE, and CodeBoost, but they look very involved ( EDG even though many say it's the best, it is a bit out of my price range ), the next thing I thought of was Eclipse since I know it can generate the AST for Java but I don't know if it can do the same for C++. I've looked for tutorials to no avail so I come here seeking for help/advice.

Comment: The ability to parse Java doesn't mean anything regarding the ability to parse C++.   However, Eclipse does has some kind of C++ parser in the form of CDT.  AFAIK, the parser is completely independent of the one for Java, including having radically different APIs.

Comment: I would still be interested in an Eclipse solution to this problem. Forgive my wording, I didn't meant to imply that just because Eclipse parses Java it must parse C++, but I have read that it does. I am just not able to find good examples on how to parse a C++ source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT 5/23:

GIYF: The phrase "Eclipse C++ parser" fed to Google produces this line to the CDT documentation:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/Overview_of_Parsing

Regardless of which parser you choose, you'll find that dealing with it is involved.
It isn't the parser machinery; its C++ itself.

CDT does parse C++.  I don't know if it does C++11 yet.  I know there is an attempt
to build refactoring tools on C++ with it, and that process is producing apparantly usable but not great results.     One of the issues is that CDT apparantly can't modify its ASTs; you have to emit some kind of text patch and reprocess the source code.

If you have examined that set of C++ parsers, you should consider our [C++11 front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html).

It produces ASTs and symbol tables, and control flow analysis.  It can analyze/transform the code, and regenerate compilable source code.   And it includes general purpose transformation machinery underneath, that applies directly to the trees.   You don't have to emit patches and reparse.

PS: EDG and Rose are really the same; Rose simply uses EDG.
EDG doesn't have any transformational capability.   Rose does have it but it seems convoluted, but then I'm spoiled by my own tools.

Comment: How can I get a demo version of that product?

Comment: Contact the company for an offline discussion.